# Cast CloudLegacySolrClient to CloudSolrClient

Tags: java, intellij-idea, solr, architecture, solrj

In solrJ9.2.0 CloudSolrClient does not support a Builder with HttpClient instead now it takes Http2SolrClient, Old CloudSolrClient is now renames as CloudLegacySolrClient, how do modify this code so that i can use CloudSolrClient as CloudLegacySolrClient is deprecated in Solr 9.2.0

```
@Component
public class SolrClientFactoryImpl{

    private final HttpClient httpClient;

    @Autowired
    public SolrClientFactoryImpl(final HttpClient httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    @Override
    public SolrClientWrapperImpl getSolrClient(final ZookeeperConnectionSpecifier zk) {
        logger.debug("Creating CloudSolrClient for cluster {}", zk.getZkConnectionString());
        return new SolrClientWrapperImpl(
              new CloudLegacySolrClient.Builder(
                    zk.getInstancesAsString(),
                    Optional.of("/" + zk.getRootNode().orElse("")))
                          .withHttpClient(httpClient)
                          .build());
    }
```

```
@Bean
public CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient(
      final SolrHttpClientProperties solrHttpClientProperties,
      final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingManager,
      final MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    final HttpRequestRetryHandler requestRetryHandler = new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler() {

        @Override
        protected boolean handleAsIdempotent(final HttpRequest request) {
            // we can't tell if a Solr request is idempotent
            return false;
        }
    };

    final ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy keepAliveStrategy = new DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {

        @Override
        public long getKeepAliveDuration(final HttpResponse response, final HttpContext context) {
            final long maxFromHost = super.getKeepAliveDuration(response, context);
            return Math.min(solrHttpClientProperties.getConnectionMaxIdleSeconds(), maxFromHost);
        }
    };

    final RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
          .setSocketTimeout(solrHttpClientProperties.getSocketConnectionTimeOutSeconds()\*1000)
          .build();

    final HttpRequestExecutor httpRequestExecutor = MicrometerHttpRequestExecutor
          .builder(meterRegistry)
          .exportTagsForRoute(true)
          .build();

    return HttpClientBuilder.create()
          .setConnectionManager(poolingManager)
          .setRetryHandler(requestRetryHandler)
          .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
          .setRequestExecutor(httpRequestExecutor)
          .setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy)
          .setUserAgent("searchService")
          .build();
}\`\`\`
```

```
the constructor in @component class takes object of HttpClient which is autowired through the bean defined below, how do i modify the closeableHttpClient() method so that i returns a Http2Solrclient or if there is any way i can cast HttpClient to Http2SolrClient in getSolrClient() method since CloudLegacySolrClient is deprecated.

I tried casting HttpClient to Http2SolrClient but it did not worked
        return new SolrClientWrapperImpl(
              new CloudSolrClient.Builder(
                    zk.getInstancesAsString(),
                    Optional.of("/" + zk.getRootNode().orElse("")))
                          .withHttpClient((Http2SolrClient) httpClient)
                          .build());
```